# How to install rsync on mac while samba.org is down

Tags: terminal, homebrew, rsync

```
(! 516)->  brew install rsync
==> Installing rsync from homebrew/homebrew-dupes
==> Downloading https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync-3.1.1.tar.gz

curl: (7) Failed to connect to rsync.samba.org port 443: Operation timed out
Error: Failed to download resource "rsync"
Download failed: https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync-3.1.1.tar.gz
```

Entire https://www.samba.org/ is down.

**Any idea / alternative how to install rsync on Mac** right now?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just picking a random mirror (from the Gentoo linux distribution in this case):

https://mirrors.kernel.org/gentoo/distfiles/rsync-3.1.1.tar.gz

You could browse through the repositories of most large distributions and find various copies of the latest rsync source tar there. Source code should work on all distributions, including Mac OSX. It's the same "tarball" samba.org normally hosts.

You probably have to run `brew edit rsync` to modify the formula, if you want to install it with homebrew. Homebrew uses little scripts called formulas, written in Ruby, which tell it where to find source code, what to do with it, and how to install it.

Just replace the `https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync-3.1.1.tar.gz` lines with `https://mirrors.kernel.org/gentoo/distfiles/rsync-3.1.1.tar.gz` in that script for the time being.